# Backus-Naur Form grammar validator

Tags: compilation, binary-tree, conditional-compilation

I would like to know how to write a program that reads a file where there are rules in the form BNF and to verify it is a phrase belongs to this language.
for example with :

```
rule = ident "=" exp ";" ;
exp = art_expr | call_fn_exp;
art_expr = art_expr |"("art_expr")" | art_expr art_oper art_expr | numeric;
numeric = integer | decimal;
integer = signe  digit [exponentiel digit];
decimal = signe digit float_part;
float_part = "." exponentiel digit;
signe= ["+"|"-"] {signe};
exponentiel = ("e"|"E") ["+"|"-"];
digit =  "0".."9" {digit};
art_oper = "+"|"-"|"/"|"-"|"%";
call_fn_exp = ident"("optargs")";
optargs =  exp {"," exp};
ident = (letter|"_") {digit|letter|"_"};
letter =  "a".."z" | "A".."Z";
```

How can i check if `(12) + add(12,15) + 12` is valid?